# WordPress Website Redirect Based on Country and/or IP

Tags: redirect

How do you redirect a website to another subdomain or website depending on the visitor's country or IP?

Answer (score 0):

I've found it! Using the plugin "Redirection" does the job.

Comment: Looks promising although please include a link to the plugin in your answer

Comment: You could just google that, but here it is:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/